# My angular-datable don't work well when translate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

I have a problem when i change the langue of my datatable.
It don't change the langage specified in "dtOptions" who change in my .ts file but i don't see button and pagination anymore.
Obviously i have :

French page with button and pagination
[image]

English page without button and pagination
[image]

My .ts file

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.subscriptions.add(this.activateRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.sollicitationsRecues = data.sollicitationsRecues;

      /**
       * Permet de définir l'url selon le langage.
       */
      this.subscriptions.add(this.formulaire.currentLanguage.subscribe(language => {
        this.language = language;

        this.statutByLangue = statutsJson['default'].statuts[this.language]

        this.dateAdapter.setLocale(this.language);
        import(`../../assets/i18n/${language}.json`).then(language_json => {
          if (this.sollicitationsRecues) {
            this.location.replaceState('/' + language_json.navbar.url.sollicitationsRecues);
          } else {
            this.location.replaceState('/' + language_json.navbar.url.afficherSollicitation);
          }
        });

        if (language === 'fr') {
          this.dataTableLanguage = datatableFR['default'];
        } else {
          this.dataTableLanguage = datatableEN['default'];
        }

        if (this.dtElement && this.dtElement.dtInstance) {
          this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
            dtInstance.destroy();
            delete this.dtOptions['oLanguage'];
            this.dtOptions.language = this.dataTableLanguage;
            this.dtTrigger.next();
          });
        }
      }));

      /**
       * Reception des sollicitations depuis le back
       */
      if (this.sollicitationsRecues) {
        this.subscriptions.add(
          this.sollicitationService.getSollicitationsRecuesOrgAdmin(sessionStorage.getItem('loginName'))
          .subscribe((sollicitations: Sollicitation[]) => {
            if (sollicitations.length > 0) {
              this.sollicitations = sollicitations;
              this.statistiques = this.sollicitationService.getStatistiquesSollicitations(this.sollicitations, true, null, null);
              this.nombreSollicitation = this.sollicitations.length;
            }
            this.dtTrigger.next();
          },
            error => this.erreurHttp = error.message
          )
        );
      } else {
        this.subscriptions.add(
          this.sollicitationService.getSollictationsByCriteres({})
          .subscribe((sollicitations: Sollicitation[]) => {
            this.sollicitations = sollicitations;
            this.statistiques = this.sollicitationService.getStatistiquesSollicitations(this.sollicitations, false, null, null);
            this.nombreSollicitation = this.sollicitations.length;
            this.dtTrigger.next();
          },
            error => this.erreurHttp = error.message
          )
        );
      }
    }));

    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      autoWidth: true,
      responsive: true,
      lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
      columnDefs: [
        { targets: 3,
          type: 'date',
          render: function(data, type) {
            const date = parseISO(data);
            return type == 'display' && isValid(date) ? format(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') : data
          }
        },
        { targets: 4,
          type: 'date',
          render: function(data, type) {
            const date = parseISO(data);
            return type == 'display' && isValid(date) ? format(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') : data
          }
        }
      ],
      order: [[ 4, "desc" ]],
      language: this.dataTableLanguage,
      dom: 'lBfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy',
        'print',
        'excel'
      ]
    };

    this.subscriptions.add(this.loaderService.isLoading.subscribe((value) => {
      this.loading = value;
    }));

    /**
     * Initialisation de toutes les notifications.
     */
    this.notifications = [
      { id: 1, libelle: 'premiere notification' },
      { id: 2, libelle: 'seconde notification' }
    ];



    /**
     * Remise à vide de la variable de session "confirmation" pour empêcher son accès lorsque l'on ne passe pas par le bouton approprié.
     */
    sessionStorage.setItem('confirmation', '');

    /**
     * On récupère la valeur de l'orgAdmin depuis les variables de sessions.
     */
    this.isOrgAdmin = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('isOrgAdmin'))



    this.formulaire.changeNbResultat(undefined);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
```

My HTML file :

```
<div class="container table-responsive col-md-12">
    <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-bordered row-border" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th>{{'afficherSolicitation.numSollicitaiton' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'afficherSolicitation.sujet' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'afficherSolicitation.titre' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'afficherSolicitation.dateSaisi' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'afficherSolicitation.dateLastModif' | translate}}</th>
          <th *ngIf="isOrgAdmin && sollicitationsRecues">{{'afficherSolicitation.saisiePar' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'afficherSolicitation.statut' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{'afficherSolicitation.action' | translate}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let sollicitation of sollicitations; let i = index" class="text-center">
            <td *ngIf="!loading"><a [routerLink]="" (click)="voirSollicitation(i)">{{sollicitation.id}}</a></td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading">{{sollicitation.categoriePiste}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading">{{sollicitation.titre}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading && language === 'fr'">
              {{sollicitation.dateEnvoi | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading && language !== 'fr'">
              {{sollicitation.dateEnvoi | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading && language === 'fr'">
              {{sollicitation.dateModification | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading && language !== 'fr'">
              {{sollicitation.dateModification | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="isOrgAdmin && sollicitationsRecues && !loading">{{sollicitation.creerPar}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading">{{statutByLangue[sollicitation.statut]}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="!loading">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-center buttonTable"
              (click)="voirSollicitation(i)"><span class="material-icons">visibility</span></button>
              <button *ngIf="sollicitation.statut !== 'Fermée' && sollicitation.statut !== 'Fermée automatiquement' && sollicitation.statut !== 'Brouillon' && !sollicitationsRecues" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-center buttonTable"
              (click)="deleteSolicitation(i)"><span class="material-icons">close</span></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngIf="loading">
            <td ALIGN="center" colspan="7">
              <mat-progress-spinner class="progress-loader" [mode]="'indeterminate'">
              </mat-progress-spinner>
          </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

My datatable.en.json:

```
{
    "sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
    "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
    "sProcessing": "Processing...",
    "sSearch": "Search:",
    "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst": "First",
      "sLast": "Last",
      "sNext": "Next",
      "sPrevious": "Previous"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
      "sSortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
    },
    "buttons": {
      "copy": "Copy",
      "copySuccess": {
        "1": "Copied one row to clipboard",
        "_": "Copied %d rows to clipboard"
      },
      "copyTitle": "Copy to clipboard",
      "print": "Print",
      "excel": "Excel"
    }
  }
```

My datatable.fr.json:

```
{
    "sProcessing": "Traitement en cours...",
    "sSearch": "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
    "sLengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
    "sInfo": "Affichage de l'&eacute;l&eacute;ment _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Affichage de l'&eacute;l&eacute;ment 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement en cours...",
    "sZeroRecords": "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
    "sEmptyTable": "Aucune donn&eacute;e disponible dans le tableau",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst": "Premier",
      "sPrevious": "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
      "sNext": "Suivant",
      "sLast": "Dernier"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
      "sSortDescending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre d&eacute;croissant"
    },
    "buttons": {
      "copy": "Copier",
      "copySuccess": {
          "1": "Copie d'une ligne dans le presse-papiers",
          "_": "Copie de %d lignes dans le presse-papiers"
      },
      "copyTitle": "Copier dans<br>le presse-papiers",
      "print": "Imprimer",
      "excel": "Excel"
    }
  }
```

Comment: what happens when you remove ```sInfoThousands``` from the ```.en``` file? since that is the only property not in the ```.fr``` config. Can you also check with dev tools if the buttons are in the DOM or not?

Comment: I have the same problem